# How to get data after login with Next-Auth and MySQL

Tags: reactjs, next.js13

I want to get data after login with NextAuth and MySQL

I don't know that after successfully logging in, I can't get data from useSession from "next-auth/react";

code get data from useSession

`<span className="text-sm">{session?.user?.name}</span>`

Can anyone explain to me specifically and can you give me the NextAuth masonry documents?

my code

table User

```
CREATE TABLE USERS (
    ID CHAR(36) DEFAULT (UUID()) PRIMARY KEY,
    USERNAME VARCHAR(255),
    EMAIL VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    PASSWORD VARCHAR(255),
    EMAIL_VERIFY BOOL DEFAULT FALSE,
    ADMIN BOOL DEFAULT FALSE,
    AVATAR TEXT,
    CREATE_AT DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    UPDATE_AT DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

nextauth.ts

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";
import connection from "@/database/connect-database";

const handler = NextAuth({
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      id: "credentials",
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        EMAIL: { label: "EMAIL", type: "text" },
        PASSWORD: { label: "PASSWORD", type: "password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        await connection;
        try {
          const [user]: any = await connection.execute(
            "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE EMAIL = ?",
            [credentials?.EMAIL]
          );

          if (user.length === 0) {
            throw new Error("Email does not exist");
          }
          const isPasswordCorrect = await bcrypt.compare(
            credentials?.PASSWORD as never,
            user[0].PASSWORD
          );

          if (isPasswordCorrect) {
            return user;
          } else {
            throw new Error("Wrong Credentials!");
          }
        } catch (err: any) {
          throw new Error(err.message);
        }
      },
    }),

  pages: {
    error: "/auth/sign-in",
  },
});

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

image api

[image]

Comment: You're trying to access the user's name from the session object with ```{session?.user?.name}```. If the session object is ```undefined```, this will result in an error. If not so, the possible reason of not getting the data is maybe the ```SessionProvider``` is not added to ```pages/_app.js``` and the session data is not being returned from the server or the session state is not being updated.